# Usage of regex in c++11

Tags: c++, regex

I'm using VS2010.

I have problem with regular expression

What regular expression should I use to search in string

```
std::string foo("s:{foo} s1:{bar}");
```

words foo, bar
and possibly know they position.

I thought that something like

```
std::regex r("\\{.*\\}");
```

should work. But it doesn't. 
Why?

Comment: Maybe you should read some tutorial on regex before getting started: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: what error are you getting..what is it matching and what is it not matching..you need to specify all these things in the question

Answer (score 1):

for string `s:{foo} s1:{bar}`

`{.*}` would match `{foo} s1:{bar}`

`.*` matches **greedily** that is it would match till the **last** `}` in your case

---

`{.*?}` would match `{foo}` and in the next match it would match `{bar}`

`.*?` matches **lazily** that is it would match till the **first** `}` in your case

Comment: btw. could someone tell why in hell two spaces   
like in formatting tutorial do not do me <br/>

Comment: @makefun what is  `two spaces`..sorry but cant understand what u r asking for

Comment: I tried to write comment here with correct formatting
in link below it is written that to make new line I should use two spaces, but it doesn't work for me.